# No se pudo cargar la informacion del proyecto

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, razor

Al crear una vista de Razor me sale el siguiente error
"There was an error running the selected code generator: Scaffolding failed. Could not load information for project C:(La ruta de mi proyecto\Model.csproj)"

Comment: Y en un proyecto en blanco te pasa lo mismo?

Comment: Si el proyecto es en la misma solucion no me deja, de hecho ni siquiera sale mensaje de error, tengo que cerrar el visual porque se "congela"

Comment: Es que si no tienes errores en un nuevo proyecto (en otra solución), lo más corto es crear uno nuevo y trasladar todo al nuevo